# How to respond to an orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

I want to display a toast message when the screen orientation changes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vnsheety,

You will have to add the following in AndroidManifest for that activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Then if you override the function `onConfigurationChanged`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            //display toast here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in the if else condition android check the orientation and in that you can show toast as you want...

```
    if (Intraday.this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){ 
    Toast.makeText(class.this, "msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

    }
    else if (Intraday.this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {      

   Toast.makeText(class.this, "msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```